# Why is isObject (with default settings) returning empty objects?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

From the documentation for [`toObject`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) it states that the `minimize` option will *remove empty objects (defaults to `true`)*
and also the documentation for [`toJSON`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toJSON) states this *method accepts the same options as `Document#toObject`*.

However I have noticed two instances where this doesn't appear to be true (I haven't done an exhaustive check yet).

My main question is: Am I missing something (this is the intended output) or is this a bug?

*Using version 3.8.7.*

Given the simple schemas:

```
var CommentSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  body: String,
  created: {
    by: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  }
});

var BlogSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  blog: String,
  created: {
    by: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    }
  },
  comments: [CommentSchema]
});

var Blog = mongoose.model('Blog', BlogSchema);
```

**Case 1**

```
Blog.findOne({
  _id: id
}, function(err, blog) {
  console.log(blog); // causes toJSON to be executed
});
// outputs:
{
  title: 'My first blog! #Super',
  blog: 'This is my very first #blog! I hope you enjoy it. #WOOHOO',
  _id: 532cb63e25e4ad524ba17102,
  __v: 0,
  comments: [], // SHOULD THIS BE INCLUDED??
  created: {
    by: 'Joe',
    date: Fri Mar 21 2014 17: 59: 26 GMT - 0400(EDT)
  }
}
```

**Case 2**

```
Blog.findOne({
  _id: id
}, 'title', function(err, blog) {
  console.log(blog); // causes toJSON to be executed
});
// outputs:
{
  title: 'My first blog! #Super',
  _id: 532caa3841176afb4a7c8476,
  created: {} // SHOULD THIS BE INCLUDED??
}
```

Comment: Note that the documentation is more specific than that: *"minimize: bool - **controls document#toObject behavior when called manually** - defaults to true"*.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, thanks for the pointer to that little tidbit (why it's not included in the referenced documentation is odd). However even if you were to manually use `blog.toJSON()` or `blog.toObject()`, case #1 still returns an empty array. Referring to my own answer, I guess the documentation means **only** objects (and not arrays which are a type of object). Again, a bit odd.

Comment: It is, but it's way down the same page... =/ While there is the `Array` Object type, and `typeof []` will report "object", they're commonly considered different things due to how arrays behave rather differently from the regular object data type, so that part's not too surprising. The docs seem a bit sparse, but I think what they mean with "manually" is not just `thing.toObject()`, but explicitly calling it with the options passed in, so needing `thing.toObject({ minimize: true })` rather than relying on implicit options that were set by you for mongoose in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, my understanding for forcing toJSON by using console.log was incorrect. To do so use: `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blog)));`

Using the correct method to show the JSON representation of the mongoose document solves case #2:

```
    Blog.findOne({
      _id: id
    }, 'title', function(err, blog) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blog))); // causes toJSON to be executed
    });
     // outputs:
     {
      title: 'My first blog! #Super',
      _id: 532caa3841176afb4a7c8476
    }
```

However, the empty array from case #1 is still returned:

```
    Blog.findOne({
      _id: id
    }, function(err, blog) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(blog))); // causes toJSON to be executed
    });
     // outputs:
     {
      title: 'My first blog! #Super',
      blog: 'This is my very first #blog! I hope you enjoy it. #WOOHOO',
      _id: 532cb63e25e4ad524ba17102,
      __v: 0,
      comments: [], // SHOULD THIS BE INCLUDED??
      created: {
        by: 'Joe',
        date: Fri Mar 21 2014 17: 59: 26 GMT - 0400(EDT)
      }
    }
```

So I guess the answer is if the documentation means only empty objects (and not arrays) than this is expected behavior.